# Using Django Credentials to Login to External API

Tags: python, django, rest, django-rest-framework, django-authentication

I'm building an application that makes user-specific API calls to an external REST API, which uses basic Base64 authentication in the header. I've hardcoded my own for testing purposes, but am preparing to deploy and will need each user to make their own calls, using their own credentials.

My initial thought was to take the `user.username` and `user.password` fields, and do a simple Base64 encoding on them to pass into the API. However, Django doesn't store the password in plain text (for obvious reasons), so this is out of the question.

Is there a way to login to this external API using the logged in user's credentials? Maybe a token or a cookie of some sort?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: To clarify, are you in control of the authentication of the external API or do you simply expect the Django credentials to match the external APIs credentials ?

Comment: In regards to tokens, I recommend using JSON web tokens, there are many articles that describe how to do it for your own auth, https://medium.com/python-pandemonium/json-web-token-based-authentication-in-django-b6dcfa42a332. Now for something like Single Sign On you would need to have either control over the external API or some other form of auth flow (e.g. like Google providing access to 3rd party apps). This is all assuming that you don't want to simply skim the authentication for an external service.

Comment: I could do either - is it possible to make it work by matching the external credentials?

Comment: Probably not, as Django's authentication does not simply use Basic Auth (if it would then yes, the Base64 encoded credentials would result in the same value for the same username and password). Still unclear how a user would signup for the use of the external API, if costs are related to it or not. But if the users trust your application you could save the credentials in a model, but this is really nothing I can recommend for you or the user.

Comment: If you are in control of both external API and both are Django, you could look into django-simple-sso, I have not used it but you could have one of the apps be the master for authentication, but too little information unfortunately to come up with a concrete recommendation.

Comment: Thanks for the follow-up. The other app is not Django, it's a strictly IE-based web app (which is why I'm building an alternate front end for it). I'll probably just have my users enter their user and pass in another form once they're logged in, which (rather than storing) will encode and send these variables directly to the API and receive a token in return.

Comment: Understood, if the API uses basic auth against an auth endpoint that provides a token for further use, that sounds slightly strange, but if so yes your easiest approach would be to assemble your own API call as you mentioned through a form POSTed to your Django app and creating a "session" by keeping the token for use until expiry or user logs out. Wish I could be of more help. Good luck.